# How is this in Q10 format?

Tags: floating-point, integer, embedded

I've just read somebody else's code and it claimed that the answer is in Q10 format. I can't figure out how is this in Q10. Here is the code:

```
// Convert x and y in such a manner that the ratio of x to y would
// produce a value in a Q10 format
cnt = 0;
bitMask = 0x80000000;

while((cnt < 10) && !(bitMask & x))
{
  x <<= 1;
  cnt++;
}
y >>= (10 - cnt);

// Calculate the slope
if (0 == x)
  slope = 0xFFFFFFFF;
else
  slope = ((uint32)x)/(uint32)y;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Without seeing where `x` and `y` come from (and how their values should be interpreted), it's not really possible to answer this question.  The result could plausibly be Q10, but it also could not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by Q10 you mean the value has 10 bits representing the fractional portion of the fixed point value.  The code in the question will produce a Q10 value if `x` and `y` inputs have the same number of fractional bits (i.e., the same "Q" value).  The input `x` is shifted left by up to 10 bits, which increases the Q value of `x` by the number of bits shifted.  If `x` is shifted less than 10 bits (to avoid an overflow) then `y` is shifted right by the remaining bits (decreasing the Q value of `y`) so that the difference between the Q values of `x` and `y` is 10.  Then `slope` is calculated as `x/y`.  When you divide fixed point values the Q value of the result is equal to the Q value of the numerator minus the Q value of the denominator.  `slope` is a Q10 because the Q value of `x` and `y` differ by 10.

Comment: You are correct about Q10. It does mean 10 fractional bits. x and y are both unsigned int32.